# Pro tools 8 Mic problem

Tags: pro-tools, microphone, mbox-2

Hello,

I have a Pro tools 8 with a Mbox 2 mini, Laptop runs a Mac OS X 10.6.8.

The problem I am receiving are my Rode NT1A microphone is recording in very low volume, turning the input 1 volume produces a large amount of white nosies, however if I tap the microphone the bang registers, however spoken dialogue can not be picked up easily, if shouting, the dialogue is picking up very quietly behind white noises.

Does anyone know how to resolve this solution?

I have tired turning the PAD on and off and ensured that 48V button on the back is on, tired recording on a separate machine, the same problem persists.

Many Thanks
Lamp.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's certainly nothing to do with ProTools!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the DigiDesign/Avid hardware (Mbox 2s and PTHD hardware from the same period, to be precise) to have some software issues, which cause problems that may seem like a problem in the hardware. So rebooting and trying to update or reset the software are first fixes. It sounds like it could be a problem with the phantom power. Unless it's the mic that's faulty/broken.

Otherwise it could be that the mbox needs to be repaired or replaced.